# Delegated Webservice call from Microsoft CRM

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, dynamics-crm, delegation

Our Microsoft Dynamics CRM needs to call a Webservice (REST) which generates a report and stores the report in the database.

The service must run as the CRM-User which creates the report, so I thought of using Delegation. The problem is that I can't pass credentials to the service due to company policy.

Is it possible to implement this impersonation/delegation without passing credentials to the service? I thought that maybe CRM passes these data implicility to the service like the context object in a plugin.

Comment: Do you expect IExecutionContext.UserId (which is crm guid) to be used by your 3rd party service?

Comment: Hi Arun

Thx for your reply. Actually I call the Rest-Service by using XmlHttp in my Javascript Webresource. In a plugin I have this IExecutionContext passed by CRM but I'm not aware of the fact that this is also passed by CRM if a service is called from a javascript webresource.

I'm wondering if CRM passes implicitly some context object.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your application looks like so I could be wrong, but I know that in theory if you are sending information to a web service through HTTP you can send the guid of the systemuser in the Execution Context and then using that information run any CRM Database operations on behalf of that user. I'll post an answer on how to do this if this sounds like something that would work for you.

Comment: Hi Peter

You're right, normally I would do that but actually the policy says that no data like userid etc. should be passed explicitly to the service. Imagine that by clicking on a custom ribbon button I call my rest service by using XMLHTTP and assume that I cannot send any additional information, lets say in the request header. The service should be able to impersonate/delegate the incoming request like a pass through thing. configuration (kerberos, etc) is done, whats missing is some kind of an implict delegation. the service is a custom service and does not expose the IExecutionContext.

Comment: If you send the service no info about who you are, it cannot know who you are.You must choose if you want integration or segregation. You might have some luck leveraging ApplicationPoolIdentity (it depends on the web service). Note that in server-to-server communications this kind of policy makes no sense and usually indicate that whoever enforces them should be replaced.

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for my late response. You're absolutely right on that. Therefore I proposed to implement CRM Web-API in the service for accessing the data.